# How can the indexation of a list be made cyclic in python?

Tags: python, list, cycle

If we have a list:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

What is the pythonic way of making the indexation of a list cyclic? Meaning i can never get indexError. And i need the indexation, therefore i can't use `cycle` with `next`
For example:

```
>>>myList[6]
2
>>>myList[-6]
5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use modulus operator, like this

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print myList[6  % len(myList)]
# 2
print myList[-6 % len(myList)]
# 5
```